# Sending Email From PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page which is used for booking room for meetings. I have form on which all the details for booking is required. I have fetched email id from the MySql db.I want to send email on click of submit button. I have 2 files namely home.php & insert.php. In home.php i have the form & insert.php inserts the data into the db. I tried the email functionality code but it's not working.
Please Help

room.php

```
<?php session_start(); 
if(isset($_GET['selecteddate']))
{
    $selecteddate=$_GET['selecteddate'];
}
else
{
    $selecteddate=date("Y-m-d");
}
?>
<html>
<head><title>MRA</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<style>
    #heading{ text-align:right;font-size: 20px;float:right;margin:50px 20px;}
    a:hover{ color:#BEBEBC; }
    a{ color:black;}
    #img{ margin:10px 10px; }
    #td{border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;}
    .name-error,.meeting-error { color: red; margin: 0 10px; }
    #plan { position: fixed; left: 50%; margin-left: -239px; top: 50%; margin-top: -150px; z-index: 10;background-color: #fff; padding: 10px; }
    #plan-bg { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; background: #000; opacity: 0.8; top: 0;display: none; z-index: 5;  }
    .close { position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 10px; cursor: pointer; }
    .close:hover { text-decoration: underline;  }
    #datepicker { width: 40%; float: left;  }
    .calender-date { padding: 10px 10px;  }
    #time-slot-msg,#alert-msg { position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; background: #fff; font-size: 25px; padding: 10px 20px; margin: -50px 0 0 -184.5px; display: none; z-index: 10;border-radius: 5px;  }
    #time-slot-msg p,#alert-msg p { font-weight: bold; } 
    #time-slot-msg .close,#alert-msg .close {  font-size: 15px; right: 20px;}   
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var $index;
    var systemdate = new Date();
    $('.meeting-error').hide();
    $(".meeting-timetable tr > td + td").click(function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('The selected time slot has already been assigned');
        } else {
        var $thisVal = $(this).prevAll('td:first-child').text();        
        var hour=$thisVal.substr(0,2);
        var min=$thisVal.substr(3,3);
        var d = new Date ("<?php print $selecteddate; ?>");
        var n = d.getFullYear();
        var m = d.getDate();
        var k = d.getMonth();
        var userdate=new Date(n,k,m,hour,min,0);
        if( systemdate > userdate )
        {
            alert("Select Time Slot greater than the Current Time");
            return; 
        }
        $index = $(this).index();
        // Start time.
        $(".start-time option").each(function() {
        if (($(this).text() === $thisVal)) {
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        $(this).prevAll().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        });
        // Change end time.
        $(".end-time option").each(function() {
        if (($(this).text() === $thisVal)) {
        $(this).next().attr('selected', 'selected');
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).prevAll().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        });  
        // Date input select.
        var $date = $('.meeting-timetable tr:first-child th').text();
        var dateFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date($date));
        $('.date').val(dateFormat);
        $('#meeting').val('');
        $('.meeting-error').hide();
        // Show dialog box.             
        var _cellIndex = $(this)[0].cellIndex;
        var _rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex;
        var total_row = $('.meeting-timetable tr').length - 1;
        if( _rowIndex ==  total_row && _cellIndex == 1 ) {
                alert('You cannot select this time slot');
            }
            else $('#plan, #plan-bg').fadeIn();
            }
        });
        // On submit click change background color.
        $('.submit-button').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var selectedValue = $(".start-time option:selected").text(),
            selectedEndValue = $(".end-time option:selected").text(),
            $name = $('input[name=txtname]').val();
            if($('#meeting').val()) {
            $(".meeting-timetable tr > td").each(function()  {
            if ($(this).text() === selectedValue) {
            $(this).parent('tr').addClass('active');
                }
            if ($(this).text() === selectedEndValue) {
            var $parent = $(this).parent('tr').prevUntil('tr.active').addClass('active');
                }
        // Prev all td selected.
        $($parent).each(function(){
            });
        });
        }         
        // Form validation.
        if ($('#meeting').val() === '') { $('.meeting-error').fadeIn(); }   
        // Grab form values
        var formData = {
                'txtrname'    : $('input[name=txtrname]').val(),
                'txtname'     : $('input[name=txtname]').val(),
                'txtemail'    : $('input[name=txtemail]').val(),    
                'txtpurpose'  : $('input[name=txtpurpose]').val(),
                'attendee'    : $('select[name=attendee]').val(),
                'txtdate'     : $('input[name=txtdate]').val(),
                'btime'       : $('select[name=btime]').val(),
                'etime'       : $('select[name=etime]').val()
                }; 
        if($('#meeting').val().trim()) {
        // Ajax form submit.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insertkarma.php",
            data: formData,
            success: function()
            {   
                $('#alert-msg').fadeIn();
                $('#plan').fadeOut();
            }
        });
        } else { alert('Please enter the purpose of meeting'); } });
        // on focus function
            $('#meeting').focus(function() {
            $('.meeting-error').fadeOut();
            }).blur(function() {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
            $('.meeting-error').fadeIn();
            }
        });
        $(".close").click(function() {
        $('.pop-up').fadeOut();
        });
        // Adding calender.
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                    minDate: 0,
                    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                    onSelect: function (date) {
                        var url="karma.php?selecteddate="+date;
                        window.location.assign(url);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body background="a9.jpg">
        <a href="homepage.php"><img id="img" src="HITECHLOGO.jpg" width="150px" height="100px"></a>
        <h1 align="center" style="position:absolute;top:30px; left:600px;">KARMA <br>(3-SEATER)</h1>
        <div id="heading"><a href="homepage.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['usr_name']); ?></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="changepswd.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Change Password</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="logout.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Logout</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="UserManual.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Help</a></div>
        <hr width="100%">
        <?php
            $host="localhost"; // Host name 
            $username="root"; // Mysql username 
            $password=""; // Mysql password 
            $db_name="testmra"; // Database name 
            // Connect to server and select databse.
            $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 
            mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
            $i = 0;
            $dateEntry = "SELECT `starttime` , `status_id` , `name` , floor(( time_to_sec(`endtime`)-time_to_sec(`starttime`) )/1800) as testing FROM `karmadetails` WHERE `date` = '$selecteddate' order by starttime";
            if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$dateEntry)) {
                while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
                {
                    $starttime[$i] = $obj->starttime;
                    $status[$i] = $obj->status_id;
                    $name[$i] = $obj->name;
                    $testing[$i] = $obj->testing;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
        <table border="1" align="right" width="60%" style="border:black;">
        <tr><td id="td" colspan="3" align="center"><h1>Click to Book a Time Slot</h1></td></tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor="red" align="center" id="td">Booked</td><td align="center" id="td">Available</td></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="td" colspan="3">| <a href="karma.php"> Today </a> |</td></tr></table>
        <table class="meeting-timetable" border="1" align="right" width="60%" style="border:black;">
        <tr><th id="td" colspan="2" class="calender-date" align="center"><?php print $selecteddate; ?></th></tr>
        <tr><td id="08:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;" width="10%">08:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="08:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">08:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="09:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">09:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="09:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">09:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="10:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">10:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="10:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">10:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="11:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">11:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="11:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">11:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="12:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">12:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="12:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">12:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="13:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">13:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="13:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">13:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="14:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">14:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="14:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">14:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="15:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">15:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="15:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">15:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="16:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">16:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="16:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">16:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="17:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">17:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="17:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">17:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="18:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">18:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="18:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">18:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="19:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">19:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="19:30:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">19:30</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="20:00:00" align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;">20:00</td><td id="td"></td></tr>
        </table>
        <table></table>
        <?php
            $name=$_SESSION['usr_name'];
            $host="localhost"; // Host name 
            $username="root"; // Mysql username 
            $password=""; // Mysql password 
            $dbname="testmra"; // Database name 
            // Create connection
            $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);           
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 
            else{

                }   
            $res  = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT emailid FROM users WHERE username='$name'");     
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
            {
                $rows = $row['emailid'];

            }
        ?>
        <div id="plan" class="pop-up" style="display :none ">
        <span class="close">Close</span>
        <form align="center" method="post" id="inform">
        <h1 align="center">Meeting Details</h1>
        <table>
        <tr><td align="right"><b>Room : </td><td><input type="text" name="txtrname" value="Karma" readonly></td></tr>
        <tr><td align="right"><b>Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="txtname" readonly value="<?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['usr_name']);  ?>"   ></td></tr>
        <tr><td align="right"><b>Email Id :</td><td><input type="text" name="txtemail" readonly value="<?php echo $rows ?>"></td></tr>
        <tr><td align="right"><b>Purpose of Meeting :</td><td> <input id="meeting" type="text" name="txtpurpose"><span class="meeting-error">Enter the purpose of meeting</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td align="right"><b>No. of Attendee :</td><td><select name="attendee"><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select></td></tr>
        <tr><td align="right"><b>Date :</td><td> <input class="date" type="text" name="txtdate" readonly value="yyyy/mm/dd"></td></tr>
        <tr><td align="right"><b>Time : </td><td>Start Time <select class="start-time" name="btime">
            <option value="08:00:00">08:00</option>
            <option value="08:30:00">08:30</option>
            <option value="09:00:00">09:00</option>
            <option value="09:30:00">09:30</option>
            <option value="10:00:00">10:00</option>
            <option value="10:30:00">10:30</option>
            <option value="11:00:00">11:00</option>
            <option value="11:30:00">11:30</option>
            <option value="12:00:00">12:00</option>
            <option value="12:30:00">12:30</option>
            <option value="13:00:00">13:00</option>
            <option value="13:30:00">13:30</option>
            <option value="14:00:00">14:00</option>
            <option value="14:30:00">14:30</option>
            <option value="15:00:00">15:00</option>
            <option value="15:30:00">15:30</option>
            <option value="16:00:00">16:00</option>
            <option value="16:30:00">16:30</option>
            <option value="17:00:00">17:00</option>
            <option value="17:30:00">17:30</option>
            <option value="18:00:00">18:00</option>
            <option value="18:30:00">18:30</option>
            <option value="19:00:00">19:00</option>
            <option value="19:30:00">19:30</option>
            <option value="20:00:00" disabled>20:00</option>
        </select>
        - End Time <select class="end-time" name="etime">
            <option value="08:00:00">08:00</option>
            <option value="08:30:00">08:30</option>
            <option value="09:00:00">09:00</option>
            <option value="09:30:00">09:30</option>
            <option value="10:00:00">10:00</option>
            <option value="10:30:00">10:30</option>
            <option value="11:00:00">11:00</option>
            <option value="11:30:00">11:30</option>
            <option value="12:00:00">12:00</option>
            <option value="12:30:00">12:30</option>
            <option value="13:00:00">13:00</option>
            <option value="13:30:00">13:30</option>
            <option value="14:00:00">14:00</option>
            <option value="14:30:00">14:30</option>
            <option value="15:00:00">15:00</option>
            <option value="15:30:00">15:30</option>
            <option value="16:00:00">16:00</option>
            <option value="16:30:00">16:30</option>
            <option value="17:00:00">17:00</option>
            <option value="17:30:00">17:30</option>
            <option value="18:00:00">18:00</option>
            <option value="18:30:00">18:30</option>
            <option value="19:00:00">19:00</option>
            <option value="19:30:00">19:30</option>
            <option value="20:00:00">20:00</option>
        </select>
        </td></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
        <!--<input class="reset-button" type="reset" value="Reset">--></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div id="plan-bg" class="pop-up"></div>
        <div id="alert-msg" class="pop-up"><span class="close" onclick="window.location.reload();">Close</span><p>The selected time slot is booked.</p></div>
        <div id="time-slot-msg" class="pop-up"><span class="close">Close</span><p>This time slot is already booked.</p></div>
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
        <?php
            $user = ucwords($_SESSION['usr_name']);
            $host="localhost"; // Host name 
            $username="root"; // Mysql username 
            $password=""; // Mysql password 
            $db_name="testmra"; // Database name 
            // Connect to server and select databse.
            $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 
            mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM karmadetails WHERE name='$user' AND date='$selecteddate' AND (status_id=1 OR status_id=2)");
            echo "<table border='1' style='border:black;'>
                <tr>
                    <th id='td'>User Id</th>
                    <th id='td'>Purpose</th>
                    <th id='td'>Date</th>
                    <th id='td'>Start Time</th>
                    <th id='td'>End Time</th>
                    <th id='td'>Cancel Booking</th>
                </tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['id'] . </td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['purpose'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['starttime'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['endtime'] . "</td>";
                        echo '<td align="center" id="td"> <a href="cancelkarma.php?userid='. $row['id'].'" style="color:red" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to cancel the booking ?\')" >Cancel</a> </td>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var jqueryarray = [];
            jqueryarray = <?php echo json_encode($starttime); ?>;
            var statusarray=[];
            statusarray = <?php echo json_encode($status); ?>;
            var namearray=[];
            namearray = <?php echo json_encode($name); ?>;
            var countarray = [];
            countarray = <?php echo json_encode($testing); ?>;
            var arr = [];
            for(i = 0; i < <?php echo $i; ?>; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = jqueryarray[i];
            }
            var brr = [];
            for(i = 0; i < <?php echo $i; ?>; i++)
            {
                brr[i] = statusarray[i];
            }
            var crr=[];
            for(i=0; i< <?php echo $i; ?>; i++)
            {
                crr[i] = namearray[i];
            } 
            var drr=[];
            for(i=0; i< <?php echo $i; ?>; i++)
            {
                drr[i] = countarray[i];
            } 
            var j = 0;
            var k=1;
            var currentrow;
            $('.meeting-timetable tr').each(function() {
                if(arr[j] == $(this).find('td').attr('id')) 
                {
                    if(brr[j]==1)
                    {
                        currentrow=$(this);
                        for(k=1;k<=parseInt(countarray[j]);k++)
                        {
                            currentrow.find('td').next().css('background-color','orange').addClass('active').attr("title",namearray[j]);
                            currentrow=currentrow.next('tr');
                        }
                    }
                if(brr[j]==2)
                {
                    currentrow=$(this);
                    for(k=1;k<=parseInt(countarray[j]);k++)
                    {
                        currentrow.find('td').next().css('background-color','red').addClass('active').attr("title",namearray[j]);
                        currentrow=currentrow.next('tr');
                    }
                }
                if(brr[j]==3)
                {
                    $(this).find('td').next().css('background-color','');
                }
                if(brr[j]==4)
                {
                    $(this).find('td').next().css('background-color','');
                }
                j++;
            }
            });
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php 
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="testmra"; // Database name 

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 

    mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);

    $room = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtrname']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtname']); 
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtemail']);
    $purpose = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtpurpose']);
    $attendee = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['attendee']);
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtdate']);
    $btime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['btime']);
    $etime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['etime']);

    $sql="INSERT INTO karmadetails (room,name,purpose,attendee,date,starttime,endtime,status_id)VALUES('$room','$name','$purpose','$attendee','$date','$btime','$etime','2')";

    $to = '$email';

        $subject = "Your Booking is Done!!!";

        $message = "<p>Hello $name . You've received this E-Mail because you have booked room $room from Timings $btime to $etime on Date $date.";

        $from = "kansaramankit@gmail.com";

        $headers = "From: $from";

        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
      {
        echo "Record added";

        }
    else
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
     }
?>
```

Comment: Your mail headers must contain content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

Comment: `but it's not working` How do you know? Do you get any errors? Is the mail simply not coming? How have you tested this? Have you tested the mailserver itself? Please be specific in your problem. Don't expect us to "magicly" know it.

Comment: Mail is simply not coming. I have never used this mail functionality & used the mail code from the internet. Please guide me

Comment: check you mail server log file for the errors.

Comment: Are you tested in live server or localhost.mail function works only in liveserver

Comment: if you have the mail server installed on your local computer then check it on your servers local system, and if it is on a hosting service then check through cpanel interface and any other interface that your hosting service provides you. If you are on local system then your system should be on a public ip with port 25 open.

Comment: PHP Warning:  mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. xo3sm14473772pbb.74 - gsmtp in C:\wamp\www\a9\insertkarma.php on line 36

Comment: I want to test it first on my local host & then use it on my companies intranet.Do i need to do some sort of settings ?